# cor is not a valid character string

Tags: string, assembly

Galera, sou novo nessa linguagem e me surgiu uma dúvida nas implementações.

Quando tento fazer isso, não consigo executar. Aparece no output que "cor" is not a valid character string. Como eu faço para conseguir imprimir a variável cor na "função" imprime?

```
.data
  cor: .space 40
  pergunta: .asciiz "Digite o nome da cor:"
.macro digita
  # Preparar para imprimir a string 'pergunta'
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, pergunta
  syscall
  # Ler a string e armazenar em'cor'
  li $v0, 8  
  la $a0, cor 
  la $a1, 40
  syscall
.end_macro

.macro imprime  #deveria imprimir a string que foi armazenada em 'cor'
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, cor
.end_macro

.text
.globl executa

executa:
  #chama os dois macros criados para inserir a cor e para imprimi-lá
  digita
  imprime
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

e ae Lucas blz? no caso falto a instrução syscall na macro imprime

```
.macro imprime  #deveria imprimir a string que foi armazenada em 'cor'
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, cor
  syscall # bem aqui
.end_macro
```